# Is there a way to view sent messages on XBOX 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Is there any way for me to see messages I've sent via XBOX Live from my XBOX 360?

Answer (score 4):

There is no current way to view sent messages you sent via Xbox Live.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed answer by TheLankBoy works for Xbox 360 as well. Messages sent from the Xbox 360 were visible in the Messages screen of the Xbox One SmartGlass app. Note, you must select Messages from the menu bar of the app, the Messages tile on the Home screen is intended t work with a linked Xbox One.

Answer (score -2):

There is, just download Xbox one smart glass, it shows you everyone you have messages and everyone that has messages you in the last 28 days

Comment: The question is talking about Xbox 360, not Xbox One. The SmartGlass Apps are different.